# Finding a Pattern in string

Tags: python, regex

I have few different types of strings and want to find a particular pattern or say first number coming after the pattern in the string.Following are the example strings.

```
str1 = mprage_scan_0006__002.nii
str2 = fgre3d_scan_0005__001+orig.HEAD
str3 = f3dgr2_scan_7_afni_009.nii
str4 = 2dfgre_scan_09_08.nii
```

I want to extract numbers after 'scan_?' in every string. if it's '007' or '09' or any other way, I want to extract only the number i.e '7', '9' etc..

i did try this but looks like my solution is not that flexible as its find the first number in the string instead of first number after `'scan_'` pattern.

```
import re
a = re.findall(r'\d+', str[i])
scan_id = re.sub("^0+","",a[0])
```

Comment: `int(str1.split('_scan_')[1].rsplit('_')[0], 10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that using positive lookbehind assertion:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> str1 = 'mprage_scan_0006__002.nii'
>>> str2 = 'fgre3d_scan_0005__001+orig.HEAD'
>>> str3 = 'f3dgr2_scan_7_afni_009.nii'
>>> str4 = '2dfgre_scan_09_08.nii'
>>> 
>>> pattern = r'(?<=scan_)0*(:?\d+)'
>>> 
>>> for s in [str1, str2, str3, str4]:
...     m = re.search(pattern, s)
...     print m.group(1)
... 
6
5
7
9
>>>
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use lookbehind?

Comment: In this case probably it doesn't matter, but in general, it's more efficient not to capture something we don't want it the match, and lookbehind doesn't capture the assertion

Comment: It seems like it would be even more efficient to use a non-matching group then (by intuition, I don't have a reference for that).

Answer (score 2):

Try with this one

```
a = re.findall(r'scan_0*(\d+)', str[i])
```

What it does:

- look for *scan_*
- followed by zero or more zeroes
- followed by one ore more digits, and it selects this last group with the parentheses

Comment: the * symbol means 0 or more in regex. So it doesn't check if its followed by one or more zeros, it checks if its followed by 0 or more zeros

Comment: @Racialz Exactly what I said

Comment: @Racialz I'm sorry, I can't find the history of my answer. If you do you will see that I did not edit that part.
Anyway thank you for pointing out the correct behaviour of symbol * in regex